# Alignment Error - HTML Tables

Tags: php, html, css

So I have this

[image: screenshot]

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$cash = $row['cash'];
$exp = $row['exp'];
$maxExp = $row['max_exp'];
$health = $row['health'];
$energy = $row['energy'];
$stanima = $row['stanima'];
$maxStanima = $row['max_stanima'];
$maxEnergy = $row['max_energy'];
?>
<div id="statsBox">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="2490px" height="20px">
<?php
echo '<b><font color="#00FF00" face="verdana">$'.$row['cash'].'</font></b>';
?>
</td>
<td width="5000px" height="20px">
<center>
<?php
echo '<b><font color="white" face="verdana">'.$energy.'/'.$maxEnergy.'</font></b>';
?>
</center></td>
<td width="2510px" height="20px">
<div class="right">
<?php
echo '<a href="index.php"><b><p class="White">'.$stanima.'/'.$maxStanima.'</p></b>    </a>';
 }
}
?>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<div id="statsBox">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="2490px" height="20px">
<?php
echo '<b><font color="#00FF00" face="verdana">'.$health.'/100</font></b>';
?>
</td>
<td width="5000px" height="20px">
<center>
<?php
echo '<b><font color="white" face="verdana">'.$energy.'/'.$maxEnergy.'</font></b>';
?>
</center></td>
<td width="2510px" height="20px">
<div class="right">
<?php
echo '<a href="index.php"><b><p class="White">'.$stanima.'/'.$maxStanima.'</p></b>    </a>';
?>
</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the bottom 3 items to be moved up. Everything's inside 2 different tables. I've tried combining the tables but it messes up the alignment of the bottom middle item.

It's perfect how it is now, but I was wondering how I would decrease the table height somehow to make the bottom 3 items closer to the top?

Comment: have you tried to reduce the height of the rows from 20 say to 10?

Answer (score 0):

in the second table, you can add class and specify its height in the css or simply add inline css in the second table

`<table style="height:25px;">`

Answer (score 0):

Your need two Changes in your table 
1.   write a inline css in your table

```
<table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

1. You need a inline css in your p tag in your td on both locations

> `<p class="White" style="margin:0px;">   </p>`